# Would a leader in a monarchy be able to hand their reign over to someone else?

Tags: russia

Example: Would have Tsar Nicolas II be able to hand his reign over to someone family or non family related to continue his reign or was this prohibited?

Comment: [Abdicate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/abdicate)

Comment: Examples in recent history:  [Beatrix of the Netherlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatrix_of_the_Netherlands) and [Edward VIII of the United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_VIII)

Comment: I think there is some merit to this question, if it would focus on the ability of the resigning monarch to choose their successor. As Eric Urban's answer points out, that right was far from certain.

Comment: The question has merit, although perhaps could be better worded to make it better suited to the history stack.

Comment: yes but it doesnt deserve a on-hold status. it was a valid question. would this have been better? Would the monarch that was resigning be able to choose their successor or would it be automatically be passed onto 'next of kin'. (like andejons comment)

Comment: I think the question may have been trying to ask about handing it over to a person *of the monarch's choice*, rather than just handing it over to whoever happens to be next in line. The traditional method to do that is for the King to "adopt" someone. This was quite common in [the Roman Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoption_in_ancient_Rome#Imperial_succession) to ensure the next ruler was someone the current ruler felt was worthy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept is known as abdication. In some cases of history, leaders of a monarchy have been "allowed", or in reality coerced to give up the throne to a family member.

Since you specifically brought up Tsar Nicolas II, we can definitely say no. He attempted first to abdicate to his son, then quickly to another family member Grand Duke Michael Aleksandrovich.

The new government at the time was known as the Provisional government and did not accept this. But more importantly, this was essentially the beginning of the Russian Civil War. No party ever endorsed the Grand Duke and it was not until the end of the Russian Civil War that one party established power in Russia.

Reference material:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Duke_Michael_Alexandrovich_of_Russia#Abdication_of_Nicholas_II

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrograd_Soviet

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Civil_War

Comment: thank you, and whoever put this on hold, i couldnt find a answer thats why i asked here.

Comment: Russian Civil War started with the Bolsheviks dissolving the [All Russian Constituent Assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Constituent_Assembly) in January 1918, almost a year after Nicolas's abdication.

Comment: It some cases, abdication was normal and definitely *not* coerced.  Japan went through a period where emperors would [abdicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daij%C5%8D_Tenn%C5%8D) to avoid ceremonial and other duties while retaining power as in the culture sons were expected to be dutiful to fathers.  Part of the idea is you get a young man in the role, guided by an older, more experienced person while he learns the ropes.